How to realise online delivery of data in Android app
I have two devices on which there is an application, and when adding an entry to the database on one device, a notification about adding an entry and the entry itself should appear on the other device in the same application. How to implement this? android studio
I dont know how to realise that and waiting for you advices

First of all you should think about a high-level architecture. Should devices communicate P2P or maybe a server should be used?
With a P2P solution device(s) can use sockets to communicate with each other, pass the data.
In case of the server-backed solution, the server should use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) to pass the info to other device(s) about a new data. After receiving notification other device can query the backend for a new data.
